# Interrogative/relative pronouns with accompanying pronouns

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I understand this

> **What** are you asking **for**?

However, in longer and more complicated sentences, you'd want to put that accompanying pronoun just before the interrogative/relative one. It's a definition of 'intellectual property' from Lexico.

> A work or invention that is the result of creativity, such as a manuscript or a design, **to which** one has rights and **for which** one may apply for a patent, copyright, trademark, etc.

*(from [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/intellectual_property))*

I also kinda understand this type of sentence.

> "I need to have your name and address". "What for?"

*(from [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/what-for))*

Now let's look at this passage

> Who and **for what** gets benefits in Belarus is known only to one individual. Here lie the problems of those who are included in the inner circle and try to take advantage of their belonging to it. [...] Secondly, it’s unknown when, how, and **(1) for what** you can be stripped of the privileged status. **(2) What for**? It could be a whim or slander from a competitor. How? You’re lucky if you get off with only reproof. But what if you end up in prison and broke?

*(from [here](https://news.tut.by/economics/727089.html), in Russian)*

The first 'for what' jars with the second 'what for'. So I kinda intuitively want to swap the two words with each other in the second instance. Should I do that? And, more generally, how do you use accompanying pronouns with interrogative/relative pronouns?

Comment: Prefer: Who gets benefits in Belarus, and for what, is known only .....   The rest is okay.

Comment: Your source for that last paragraph is - as you say - in Russian.  So what are you quoting - a machine translation (Google Translate or the like)?  You shouldn't expect such translations to be perfect (or even consistently good).

Comment: @rjpond I translated it myself (I'm sorry if there are some mistakes)